# How to make VS 2019 program remember previous instance preferences?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, themes, preferences

I'm currently making a text editor and I created a light and dark theme, which you can change by pressing a button. The default theme is light, but I want it to remember what was the last theme I chose. So, if I select dark and I close it, next time it opens with that theme enabled.

I also want to know how to make it remember things in general.

Comment: Have a look at [Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet). Also, this question has no relation to visual studio (which just happes to be your development environment), so please remove the tag and edit the title.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [`Properties.Settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019).

```cs
//Sets a string created in the setting
Properties.Settings.Default.FirstString = "Hello World";
//saves the property , this setting will then persist after closing the aplication.
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can save the "theme" into Settings via `Project -> Project Properties… -> Settings`.

And create a Setting named "Theme", set its value to "Light".

[image]

Then we can access the "Theme" via the following code.

```
private void btnChangeTheme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "Light")
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Theme = "Dark";
    }
    else
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Theme = "Light";
    }

    string theme = Properties.Settings.Default.Theme;
    // if(theme == "Light"){...}else{...}
    // here is the code that modify theme
    // ...
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load theme
    string theme = Properties.Settings.Default.Theme;
    // if(theme == "Light"){...}else{...}
    // here is the code that modify theme
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wait is this for Visual Studio or for my own program? I created a button that alters properties like the richTextBox's back color. So this makes it remember the change?

Comment: @alex12 It is used to save program data. To save the color info, just create a new setting to save the "RGB".